# Wordpress search results to show breadcrumb without link

Tags: php, wordpress, search, breadcrumbs

We use WordPress default search widget on our site. It shows search results using content-search.php. And everything is working fine.

Because the site is big we sometimes have duplicate page names. So we need search results to show breadcrumb type of "trail" between title and excerpt. We don't want it to be a clickable link.

**Like this:**

**Page1 > Page2 > Page3**

This is a school project so our coding skills are limited but we have a basic understanding. We are in need of a bit of code that prints breadcrumb, like above

We could not find an answer to this problem anywhere else.

EDIT: Sorry. Plugins are out of the question

Comment: Are you looking for pagination in you search page ?

Comment: Probably not. Not entirely sure. Example. We have many "administration" pages. 
So when you search "Administration", search results shows many results that are similar to each other. So we would like the result to show its full "trail" so that user can see easily which "Administration" site is in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try **breadcrumb-navxt** plugin and in your search result page put this code where you want to display the breadcrump..

```
if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
{
    bcn_display();
}
```

You have to modify the breadcrumb  according to your need in the settings panel..

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. Forgot to say that plugins are out of the question :/ Thank you for answering fast tho.

Comment: okay if you are displaying pages in search result you can set parent page and can display it as breadcrumb in the search result.

Comment: Or look at this snippet this might help: https://www.codexworld.com/wordpress-how-to-display-breadcrumb-without-plugin/